# Foundation CSS loads *: before *:after pseudo-elements too many times

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, pseudo-element

My issue is related to slow loading of CSS on my page due to too many *: before *:after being loaded... Example:

```
*, *:before, *:after {  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;   box-sizing: border-box; }
```

Now I can't figure this out. I compiled foundations app.scss and just using this app.css file and for some reason also classes like .columns or small-12, medium-12 and large-12 are being loaded several times on my page, overwriting each other. 
This is causing my css being loaded couple of seconds.

I'm using foundation-version { font-family: "/5.5.0/"; }

I was not able to find that someone else had this problem. Anybody can point me to a solution for this? Thx

Comment: dont download complete foundation download custom
http://foundation.zurb.com/develop/download.html#customizeFoundation

Comment: Well not sure if this will solve the issue becaue these classes seam to be loaded from the same line, see below:
`*, *:before, *:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}`
but Ill try and see what happens. Thx

Comment: its the same line because its minified.

Answer (score 2):

Just to let everybody know I had a problem in functions.scss file on line 11, I was missing the !global parameter `$modules: $modules !global;`. After adding this the complied css was much smaller and now I don't have any issues.